# What is the difference between _LARGEFILE_SOURCE and _FILE_OFFSET_BITS=64?

Tags: c, linux, linux-from-scratch

I understand that `-D_FILE_OFFSET_BITS=64` causes `off_t` to be 64bits. So what does `-D_LARGEFILE_SOURCE` do that isn't already done by `-D_FILE_OFFSET_BITS=64`? What do these definitions do exactly?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The GLIBC [Feature test macros](http://www.gnu.org/software/libc/manual/html_node/Feature-Test-Macros.html#Feature-Test-Macros) documentation states:

> `_LARGEFILE_SOURCE`
>   If this macro is defined some extra functions are available which rectify a few shortcomings in all previous standards. Specifically, the functions fseeko and ftello are available. Without these functions the difference between the ISO C interface (fseek, ftell) and the low-level POSIX interface (lseek) would lead to problems.
>
> This macro was introduced as part of the Large File Support extension (LFS).

So that macro specifically makes `fseeko` and `ftello` available. `_FILE_OFFSET_BITS` settings alone don't make these functions available.

(Note that if you're using a GNU dialect of C, the default with GCC, you might not need to explicitly define `_LARGEFILE_SOURCE`. You do if you use `-std=c99` for instance.)

Answer (score 10):

The other answer is wrong, as the documentation for `_LARGEFILE_SOURCE` is misleading. `_FILE_OFFSET_BITS=64` is sufficient to expose the `fseeko` and `ftello` functions, and so is a `_POSIX_C_SOURCE` macro defined to >= `200112L`.

From the glibc documentation on `_FILE_OFFSET_BITS`

> If the macro is defined to the value 64, the large file interface replaces the old interface. I.e., the functions are not made available under different names (as they are with `_LARGEFILE64_SOURCE`). Instead the old function names now reference the new functions, e.g., a call to `fseeko` now indeed calls `fseeko64`.

Always define `_FILE_OFFSET_BITS=64` to switch over to the 64-bit types on 32-bit glibc-based systems. glibc should really make it the default...

Answer (score 0):

### LFS

Large File Support (LFS), provides extra functionality required +- to access large files

- large file == On 32-bit architectures, file larger than 2GB

We can write applications **requiring LFS functionality** in one of two ways:

- **Define the `_LARGEFILE64_SOURCE` feature test macro when compiling our program. -- Use the `transitional LFS API`.**
- **Define the `_FILE_OFFSET_BITS` macro with the value 64 ++ when compiling our programs.**

### `_LARGEFILE64_SOURCE`

> Define the `_LARGEFILE64_SOURCE` feature test macro when compiling our program. -- Use the `transitional LFS API`.

**This API provides functions capable of handling 64-bit file sizes and offsets.**

- These functions have the same names as their 32-bit counterparts,

  ++ but have the suffix 64 appended +- to the function name.
- Among these functions are

  ```
  fopen64(), 
  open64(), 
  lseek64(), 
  truncate64(), 
  stat64(), 
  mmap64(), 
  setrlimit64().
  ```
- @eg::

  ```
  fd = open64(name, O_CREAT | O_RDWR, mode);
  ```

### `_FILE_OFFSET_BITS`

> Define the `_FILE_OFFSET_BITS` macro with the value 64 ++ when compiling our programs.

**This automatically converts all of the relevant 32-bit functions and data types into their 64-bit counterparts.**

- @eg:: for example,

  calls to `open()` are actually converted into calls to open64(), and

  the `off_t` data type is defined +- to be 64 bits long.
- @ie:: In other words,

  we can recompile an existing program +- to handle large files without needing +- to make any changes +- to the source code.

### vs

- Using `_FILE_OFFSET_BITS` is clearly simpler than using the `_LARGEFILE64_SOURCE (transitional LFS API)`.
- `_LARGEFILE64_SOURCE (transitional LFS API)` is now obsolete.
- **`_FILE_OFFSET_BITS` is preferred.**

### reference

> The Linux Programming Interface
>
> - (most content was directly copied from here)