# ftello() and fseeko() android build errors

Tags: android, c, fseek, ftell, large-file-support

I am trying to build Android L for 64-bit architecture.

My code goes like:

```
#if (HAS_LARGE_FILE_SUPPORT)
#define _FILE_OFFSET_BITS 64   //Defined in header file


/*Some File operations*/
#if HAS_LARGE_FILE_SUPPORT
     return fseeko(iFile, offset, seekmode);
#else
     return fseek(iFile, offset, seekmode);


/*Some File operations*/
    #if HAS_LARGE_FILE_SUPPORT
         return ftello(iFile, offset, seekmode);
    #else
         return ftell(iFile, offset, seekmode);
```

I am getting below `ftello` and `fseeko` errors:

```
error: call to 'ftello' declared with attribute error: not available with _FILE_OFFSET_BITS=64

error: call to 'fseeko' declared with attribute error: not available with _FILE_OFFSET_BITS=64
```

I checked  about `fseeko` and `ftello`, on the manual pages it is mentioned that defining `_FILE_OFFSET_BITS` with the value 64 will turn `off_t` into a 64-bit type.
Still I am seeing this error.
I checked about this error but couldn't find any satisfactory answer.

It will be really helpful if anyone can help me with this.

Comment: Do you define `-D_LARGEFILE_SOURCE` (See http://stackoverflow.com/q/14184031/694576)?

Comment: @alk Thanks for replying, I tried defining the above flag also, but still I am getting same error.


`#define _LARGEFILE_SOURCE 1`

`#define _LARGEFILE64_SOURCE 1`

Comment: Perhaps the problem is in the prototypes for the functions.  that return type of 'return' probably is not correct.

Comment: this is the correct syntax for ftello() : `int fseeko(FILE *stream, off_t offset, int whence);` which does not match the prototypes you posted

Comment: @user3629249: "*... correct syntax for ftello() : `int fseeko(...`*" Err, what please?

Comment: Works perfectly for me. Do you define the macros in your source? I believe that's to localized. You have to define them in your Application.mk. `APP_CPPFLAGS += -D_LARGEFILE_SOURCE -D_FILE_OFFSET_BITS=64`

Comment: It should also be noted, that `ftell` only accepts one argument, the `FILE*`. And `fseek` is only changed, that offset accepts an `off_t` and `ftell` returns an `off_t`, instead of just `long`.

Comment: @alk He is correct, though. The signatures are as follows: `int fseeko(FILE *stream, off_t offset, int whence)` and `off_t ftello(FILE *stream)`. Taken from the linux man pages [here](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/ftello.3.html).

Comment: I cannot reproduce your error, could you show us your `Application.mk` and `Android.mk`, please?

Comment: @user3629249: I was referring to your comment relating: `ftello` and `fseeko`, even quoting it.

Comment: @Leandros: My comment was not about right or wrong, but of what *user3629249* actually way trying to express. Just re-read the comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32826175/ftello-and-fseeko-android-build-errors?noredirect=1#comment53556232_32826175

Comment: @alk Oh. haha. Missed that.

Answer (score 1):

I solved similar issue by specifying api to 24 when create standalone ndk

```
./make_standalone_toolchain.py --arch arm --api 24 --stl libc++ --install-dir /tmp/ndk
```

From ndk file `sysroot/usr/include/stdio.h`, it looks like `ftello` only support for api greater or equal than 24

```
#if __ANDROID_API__ >= 24
int fgetpos(FILE* __fp, fpos_t* __pos) __RENAME(fgetpos64) __INTRODUCED_IN(24);
int fsetpos(FILE* __fp, const fpos_t* __pos) __RENAME(fsetpos64) __INTRODUCED_IN(24);
int fseeko(FILE* __fp, off_t __offset, int __whence) __RENAME(fseeko64) __INTRODUCED_IN(24);
off_t ftello(FILE* __fp) __RENAME(ftello64) __INTRODUCED_IN(24);
#endif /* __ANDROID_API__ >= 24 */
```

Answer (score 0):

the first `#if` is being applied to the whole posted code and not just to the next line.

similar conditions exist for the other `#if` and `#else` compile conditionals,

I.E. each `#if` ... must be ended with a `#endif`